# Controlling leader election of Apache Kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

I have an existing application having Jms based communication in which two consumer nodes(Active/Passive) will be connecting to a producer through Jms queue. Here when the first consumer (C1) starts it will become an Active node and starts consuming events from queue. When the second consumer (C2) is started, it will be a Passive node. If C1 goes down, C2 becomes active and starts consuming events. When C1 is restarted it will become passive node.

I am trying to convert this with Apache Kafka. With Single Topic, Single ConsumerGroup with two consumers.

Issue:
When first Consumer K-C1 is started it will be active and starts consuming messages. **When the second Consumer K-C2 is started, the zoo-keeper is making the K-C2 as active**.

Is there a way to control this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

As long as both consumers are stateless, it shouldn't matter which one is active or passive. In my experience, the first consumer to the partition typically holds onto the active state, but this is largely determined by the rebalancing protocol, which you cannot control

You could try adjusting the `partition.assignment.strategy` settings, though